# Count how many products inside page/post in a custom post type and display

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, product

I have a custom post type - collection

So then I add pages, inside those pages are shortcode to display woocommerce products that have same taxonomy

So for example on the collection page, I add a new page called "Jeans" and I tick checkboxes "denim", "faded", "worn-out" which are custom taxonomies

So on this page will display products that have those taxonomies

This is working fine currently

```
Now I display all the pages in "collection"

Jeans (3)
Slacks (5)
Shorts (2)
```

This is my problem now, I cannot count the number of products inside those pages

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'collection',
    'order'    => (isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : 'ASC'),
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'posts_per_page' => 100,
    'paged' => $paged
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', 'collection' );
        echo '<br>';
        echo 'Number of products: '.$loop->post_count;
    endwhile;
else :
    get_template_part( 'no-results', 'archive' );
endif;
```

I am sorry I am still confused what to ask... :-(

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`get_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term) for that.

you should use this code with your taxonomy

```
$term = get_term( 1, 'category' );
echo    'count: '. $term->count;
```